# nginx + Xdebug + PhpStorm = 404 error?

Tags: nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

The last few days, I've successfully installed and set up Xdebug and PhpStorm to work properly with several remote servers at my new job.  However, one server is giving me problems and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The difference between this server and the others is that this is the only one running nginx instead of Apache.

Normally I SSH in to the server, get everything set up on that side, then follow steps in the PhpStorm menu, starting with the validation.  This is where the problem is.  When I try to validate, I receive the following:

[image: Validation error message]

Here are my PHP settings:

[image: xdebug settings]

I'm not too knowledgeable about Linux just yet so it's possible that I'm missing something stupid, but at the moment I'm very perplexed.  I'm able to upload/modify files with PhpStorm so it's not like the program isn't able to get in at all, it's only with the validation and xdebug.

If there's some data you need me to show, let me know and I'll add it when I get back in on Monday.

Comment: Check your nginx logs: see what file IDE has requested and see if it's present. AFAIK it will be uploading some php script that does those checks. So it's possible that file is somehow unreachable or was uploaded into wrong place etc. In any case: validation is fully optional (I, for example, pretty never run it, as for me debugging was setup once and it works).