# How do I test the Webserver debug validation of PhpStorm with Laravel/Valet/Xdebug?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-valet

In case the validation is started, the file is for a moment (100ms) visible in the projects folder under resources. Then immediately disappears and the validation tools says 404.

I already tested to manually put the code of the validation file into the Laravel public folder.

Error message is the same as here [nginx + Xdebug + PhpStorm = 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721725/nginx-xdebug-phpstorm-404-error) and I use Valet. I assume that one of the components of Valet is causing this problem.

I‘m using mac HighSierra, installation of Valet using homebrew.

Please let me know what info I have to provide, to help me and others.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why your path points to `resource/views` folder? It's not accessible via http. Point it to the `public` folder so IDE can reach it directly.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That was the wrong screenshot, corrected it now.

Comment: Is `~/Sourcetree/laravel54/attachload56/public` the actual web root, or you copy sources from this folder to the web root with a deployment configuration? If the latter, you should use the Remote Web Server option as otherwise PhpStorm won't upload the script to the web root. Also, the filename is not needed in the URL.

Comment: Hello,

seems the problem is caused by Valet, the macOS webserver for Laravel.

I checked the points you suggested, but had no luck.

So I thought to give classic `php artisan serve` a try, and was lucky.
It worked and validation using `/public` folder was working.

However, as the title contains "Valet", this must be considered "Unanswered until now, but workaround available."